# What to do when Wilcoxon test returns some 0 p-values?

Tags: r, statistical-test

I'm performing the Wilcoxon test with R in a large List (containing 86 data frames with a variable number of rows and values). I don't understand why after p-values < 10^-307 it returns some p-values = 0 and then it returns with "normal" values.
This condition occurs with data frames with a very high number of rows (about 4000 or more), but not in data frames with about 1000 rows.
Am I getting the script wrong or is it possible to get 0 values? If so, is there a particular way to interpret them?

Here I report my script:

```
for (i in 1 : length(List)) {   
    for(j in 2 : (nrow(List[[i]]) - 1)){
        divider <- (List[[i]][j,2])
        ValueInfe <- List[[i]][List[[i]][,2] < divider ,]
        ValueSupUgu <- List[[i]][List[[i]][,2] >= divider ,]
        if(j == 2){Num_ValoreInfe <- as.numeric(ValoreInfe[2])}
        if(j!= 2){Num_ValoreInfe <- as.numeric(ValoreInfe[,2])}
        Num_ValoreSupUgu <- as.numeric(ValoreSupUgu[,2])
        b <- wilcox.test(Num_ValoreInfe, Num_ValoreSupUgu)
        List2.0[[i]][j,3] <- b$p.value
    }
```

}

Here is an example of my results:

```
0.000000e+00
8.343024e-02
1.435822e-02
2.716505e-03
5.370877e-04
1.089895e-04
2.250558e-05
4.706192e-06
9.936437e-07
2.114061e-07
4.526195e-08
9.741929e-09
2.106339e-09
4.572291e-10
9.960156e-11
9.960156e-11
[...]
0
0
0
0
0
[...]
2.114061e-07
9.936437e-07
4.706192e-06
2.250558e-05
1.089895e-04
5.370877e-04
2.716505e-03
1.435822e-02
0.000000e+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the smallest number that R can distinguish from zero is about 1e-308 (i.e., 10^(-308)) - specifically, `.Machine$double.xmin`=2.225074e-308. More precisely, R can handle *slightly* smaller values: `?Machine` says:

> Note that on most platforms smaller positive values than
> ‘.Machine$double.xmin’ can occur.  On a typical R platform the
> smallest positive double is about ‘5e-324’.

If you want to deal with numbers smaller than that, you have to do something clever like keeping track of their logarithms instead (`log(.Machine$double.xmin)` is -708, you could easily keep track of *much* smaller numbers that way ). Some of the p-value computations in R allow you to retrieve the log-p-value rather than the p-value, but the Wilcoxon test doesn't have such a capability.

While it might be possible to build such a capability from scratch if you needed it badly enough, researchers usually just treat such p-values as "extremely small";you could say "<1e-308" if you wanted. The only research field I've seen where people worry about the precise values of such tiny p-values is in bioinformatics, where the p-value is treated as a metric in its own right rather than a qualitative indicator of the clarity of a statistical difference.

Here's a small example that tests the p-value of non-overlapping sets with progressively larger sample sizes, showing the p-value decreasing  and then underflowing to zero (see the points lying on the lower y-axis at the right edge of the plot):

```r
w <- function(n=20) {
    wilcox.test(1:n,1e6+1:n)$p.value
}
nvec <- seq(20,1000,by=10)
pvec <- sapply(nvec,w)
```

[image: Wilcox test p-values]

---

### hacking the log-p values

Digging into the code inside `stats:::wilcox.test.default`, we can find the place where the p-values are computed from the test statistic and the group-wise sample sizes and re-compute them with `log.p=TRUE`. The code below skips a few details like accounting for ties and allowing different alternative hypotheses (i.e. this is assuming a two-sided test).

This gives you the *natural* log of the p-value; you can convert back to log10 by multiplying by `log10(exp(1))` ...

```r
wilcox_log_p <- function(x,y,exact=FALSE,correct=TRUE,...) {
    ## assume two-sided
    w <- wilcox.test(x,y,...)
    n.x <- length(x)
    n.y <- length(y)
    STATISTIC <- w$statistic
    if (exact) {
        if (STATISTIC > (n.x * n.y/2)) {
            return(pwilcox(STATISTIC - 1, n.x, n.y, 
                   lower.tail = FALSE, log.p=TRUE))
        }
        return(pwilcox(STATISTIC, n.x, n.y, log.p=TRUE))
    } else {
        NTIES <- 0 ## assume no ties!
        z <- STATISTIC - n.x * n.y/2
        SIGMA <- sqrt((n.x * n.y/12) * ((n.x + n.y + 1) - 
                 sum(NTIES^3 - NTIES)/((n.x + n.y) * (n.x + n.y - 
                  1))))
            if (correct) {
                CORRECTION <- sign(z) * 0.5
            }
            z <- (z - CORRECTION)/SIGMA
            PVAL <-  log(2) + min(pnorm(z, log.p=TRUE), 
                             pnorm(z, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p=TRUE))
        return(PVAL)
    }
}

w <- function(n=20) {
    wilcox.test(1:n,1e6+1:n, exact=FALSE)$p.value
}
w2 <- function(n=20) {
    wilcox_log_p(1:n,1e6+1:n)
}
nvec <- seq(20,1100,by=10)
pvec <- sapply(nvec,w)
pvec2 <- sapply(nvec,w2)
```

```r
dd <- data.frame(n=rep(nvec,2),p=c(log(pvec),pvec2),
                 method=rep(c("default","log_p"),each=length(nvec)))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(dd, aes(n,p,colour=method)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
    scale_x_log10()
```

[image: log-p-value curves]

Comment: I had imagined it could be a problem of approximation. But to dispel any doubt, I created a vector of value 1e-311 and strangely it reads it correctly (so it doesn't approximate it to 0). maybe r can read such small values ​​only for vectors and not for data frames?

Comment: R can handle *slightly* smaller values: try `10^(-301:-350)` (the values don't actually underflow to zero until we get to 1e-324). The value given by `.Machine$double.xmin` is technically the "the smallest non-zero normalized floating-point number". I'd have to go into more technical detail to explain why we can go a bit lower.  But the qualitative idea is the same. (see edit)

Comment: Unfortunately I think I will need the log p-value . Could you please tell me how to set up the script to get it?

Comment: You can see the code for computing the p-value here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/stats/R/wilcox.test.R#L287-L293 . This code calls the `pwilcox()` function, which does have a `log.p` argument.  So if you extract the test statistic and call `pwilcox(..., log.p=TRUE)`, you can get the log-p value ...

Comment: see edits.  We need the approximate, not the exact p-values for such extreme sample sizes ...